# how to post on facebook friends wall using fbrequest programmatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I searched every where but not getting the single hint how to do that....i got some code also but it is not working ... can anyone suggest me any tutorial or sample code to do that !!! thanks in advance 
i am trying following code::

```
-(void)inviteFriend:(CustomButton *)sender
{

    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",sender.inviteUserId];
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];

        hudApp = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hudApp.labelText = @"Page Sharing...";
        [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60*5];

        // NSString *fbMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
        NSString *fbMessage = @"hello testing";


        NSMutableDictionary* params=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fbMessage, @"message", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken, @"access_token", nil];

        NSLog(@"feed::%@",str);

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:str
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result,NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"result::%@",result);


                 if(error)
                 {
                  NSLog(@"fail : %@",error.localizedDescription);
                hudApp.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription];
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      NSLog(@"Success facebook post");
                                      hudApp.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Success"];
                                      // txtView.text = @"success";
                                      NSLog(@"success");
                                  }

                                  hudApp.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                                  [self performSelector:@selector(dismissHUD:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
                              }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_stream"];
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state,NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"session.permissions ? : %@", session.permissions);
                                      [self sessionDoneForPageShare:session state:state error:error withuserid:str];
                                  }
         ];
    }


}


-(void)sessionDoneForPageShare:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error withuserid :(NSString *)usreid
{
    //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];

    NSLog(@"feed::%@",usreid);
    hudApp = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hudApp.labelText = @"Page Sharing...";
    [self performSelector:@selector(timeout:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60*5];

    //NSString *fbMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"];
    NSString *fbMessage = @"hello testing";

    NSLog(@"State : %d **** Facebook Message : %@",state,fbMessage);

   // NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: fbMessage, @"message", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary* params=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fbMessage, @"message", FBSession.activeSession.accessToken, @"access_token", nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:usreid
                         parameters:params
                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                  completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                              if(error)
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"fail : %@",error.localizedDescription);
                                  // txtView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription];
                                  NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription]);
                                  hudApp.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error.localizedDescription];
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  NSLog(@"Success facebook post");
                                  hudApp.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Success"];
                                  //txtView.text = @"success";
                                  NSLog(@"success");
                              }

                              hudApp.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                              [self performSelector:@selector(dismissHUD:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
                          }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to post to a friend's wall, you need to make a request to `/{friend_id}/feed`. However, Facebook has [disabled posting to friends' wall since February 6, 2013](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/):

> **Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**
>
> We will remove the ability to post to a user's friends' walls via the Graph
> API. Specifically, posts against [user_id]/feed where [user_id] is
> different from the session user, or stream.publish calls where the
> target_id user is different from the session user, will fail. If you
> want to allow people to post to their friends' timelines, invoke the
> feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or
> action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the
> friend approves the tag). For more info, see this blog post.

Comment: It is possible to post or share text from ios app without showing pop up ?